# How to get conditional SUM?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a conditional sum based on another column. For example, suppose I have this dataset:

```
ID  Date    Type    Total
-----------------------
5   12/16/2019  0   7
5   12/16/2019  1   0
5   12/17/2019  0   7
5   12/17/2019  1   7
5   12/18/2019  0   7
5   12/18/2019  1   0
5   12/19/2019  0   7
5   12/19/2019  1   7
5   12/20/2019  0   7
5   12/20/2019  1   7
5   12/23/2019  0   7
5   12/24/2019  0   7
5   12/25/2019  0   7
5   12/26/2019  0   7
5   12/27/2019  0   7
```

If there is a type of 1 then I only want that data for that data, else if there is only 0 then I want that data for that date.

So for 12/16/2019 I would want the value 0. For 12/23/2019 - 12/27/2019 I would want the value 7.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a date `12/23/2019 - 12/27/2019`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma His sample data had the date 12/23/2019 - 12/27/2019

Comment: Is that possible to have for example '5, 12/27/2019, 0, 6'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, date order by type desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple ROW_NUMBER can handle this quite easily. I changed some of the column names because reserved words are just painful to work with.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , SomeDate Date
    , MyType int
    , Total int
)

insert @Something values
(5, '12/16/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/16/2019', 1, 0)
, (5, '12/17/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/17/2019', 1, 7)
, (5, '12/18/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/18/2019', 1, 0)
, (5, '12/19/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/19/2019', 1, 7)
, (5, '12/20/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/20/2019', 1, 7)
, (5, '12/23/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/24/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/25/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/26/2019', 0, 7)
, (5, '12/27/2019', 0, 7)

select ID
    , SomeDate
    , MyType
    , Total
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by SomeDate order by MyType)
    from @Something
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple aggregation . . . well, and `case`:

```
select id, date, max(type),
       coalesce(max(case when type = 1 then total end),
                max(total)
               ) as total
from t
group by id, date;
```

This formulation is assuming that you have only types `0` and `1` and at most one of each type on each day for a given `id`.